# Cannot edit Triggered Send in Salesforce

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect

I am not able to update the Triggered Send definition in Salesforce. After deactivating, when I click on edit, its shows me the below error every time -

"The link you followed wasn’t valid for your session. Return to the previous page, refresh it, and try again. "

Have tried clearing cache, new browser and everything.

What could be wrong?